# php: modrewrite for different directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i'm having the following directory structure:

`/front/index.php` <- website root

`/admin/img/` <- extra images

so for including images i'm using this path: ../admin/img/

the problem is that i can't use `../` on my server so i need to remap the whole path.

how can i do this using modrewrite?

i'd simply like to map it from `../admin/img/` to `admin/img/`

any ideas if this is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^\.\.(/admin/img/.*)$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: this is my "lame" version: what u think about it? RewriteRule ^img/admin/up/(.*)$ ../admin/up/$1 [L]

Comment: Looks good but you can save some redundancy be writing: `RewriteRule ^img/(admin/up/(.*)$ ../$1 [L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to symlink the directory? It's pretty quick and easy, though it doesn't address any paths in your app.